# How to Validate the non active record models in rspec?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

```
#item class
class Item
 include ActiveModel::Model
   #validations from activemodel class

    validates :url, presence: true
    validates :text, presence: true 
    attr_accessor :url
    attr_accessor :text    

    def initialize (url,text)
          @url=url
          @text=text
    end 
end
  --------------------------------------------------------

RSpec.describe Item, type: :model do
 before :each do
   @url="www.fb.com"
   @text="to see fb"
   @item=Item.new(@url,@text)
 end

    it { (@item).to validate_presence_of(:url) }

end
```

it shows error in rspec No method error on validate_presence_of all my remaining test are passing all the validations are showing no method error

Comment: Do you have ``shoulda`` gem in your Gemfile? https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda Also, please: can you indent properly your code?

Comment: No if the gem is having more than 100 contributors the only i can use that gem. And for indentation this is my first question with program.

Comment: Thanks for editing, much better now. I don't understand what you say about gem contributors.

Comment: Its complicated client requirements.Anyway Thanks for Your suggestion It worked perfectly.

Comment: As far as I know, ``validate_presence_of`` is provided by ``shoulda`` gem. If you cannot use that gem, then you cannot use that helper.

Comment: If no option available.I am going to use your suggestion only.I thought it is from Activerecord.

Comment: I'm not sure your are understanding what I mean. I do not understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have the `shoulda` gem in your `Gemfile`. And check the syntax, shoulda expectations should look like this:

```
describe Item do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:url) }
end
```

Comment: I edited the new code but it showing  
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Comment: I changed my code without argument in constructor and tried Yours .But it shows again no method error

Comment: I got it @dgilperez suggestion of using shoulda gem helped.